# Moved SQL databases for SharePoint 2010 and now have a 3351 error

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, sql

I moved the SQL databases from a local instance to a remote SQL server. All permissions are the same. Everything seems to work but now I'm getting a 3351 SQL error every 30 minutes from the local server account trying to access the remote configuration database.

> SQL database login for 'SharePoint_ConfigDatabase' on instance
>   'SHAREPOINTSERVER\SHAREPOINT' failed. Login failed for user
>   'SHAREPOINTSERVER$'.

All Sharepoint services are set to domain accounts except for admin and tracing which are set to "local system". Could this be the issue?

Comment: Did you add the SHAREPOINTSERVER computer account to the new SQL logins?

Comment: That is the issue paramount, and trevors question is the solution, add the sharepoint accounts back into sql server.